# Indefinite article with country's name? The New York Times article has it

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

The paragraph from [the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/26/world/asia/narendra-modi-defies-expectations-with-mix-of-soft-and-severe-in-india.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&version=HpSumSmallMediaHigh&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&_r=0) reads...

> Rarely has any world leader come full circle the way Mr. Modi has: Denied a United States visa for nearly a decade as punishment for his handling of religious riots that broke out in the state he then led, Mr. Modi flies into New York as an immensely popular leader and a sought-after strategic partner, viewed as uniquely capable of balancing the might of ***a rising China.***

I wonder this indefinite article. What am I missing?

Comment: Of course there's only one China, and it actually _is_ rising. But using an indefinite article here creates a kind of distance (to that fact you would rather ignore, but you can't).

Comment: has article to do anything with adjective when it actually refers to a proper noun? May I say myself *a good Maulik?* :)

Comment: Yes, assuming there is a also bad Maulik. *In this instance*, you would be good.

Answer (score 4):

**"a sagging Euro", "a rising China", "an ideologically divided USA"**

The indefinite article is correct usage in such locutions, where it means that the quality or property is "now |  currently | at this moment in history" true or in effect for the noun in question (at other times, it might not be true).

Comment: May I say.. *"A struggling Tim Romano?"*

Comment: Yes, locations like "a struggling US economy" and  "a struggling {person-name|proper noun}" imply the same thing, the quality or feature is currently in effect for the noun in question.  `Newcaster: a struggling Chelsea side overcomes Manchester City in overtime.`

Comment: using that way with a noun is okay. I learned this thing used with *proper noun*. New to me!